# Copy random files by 5 each to different folder

Tags: python, file, random

I have a big list of files, that I was able to make in a random order (with a custom column "random number"). (I even made the list of these files in a txt list file for some reason).

But now I need to put them into.. lets see....740 files divide by 5...
into 148 new folders. Ok, I can make new 148 folders with an extDir utiity, but how can I copy each 5 files into a one of a 148 folders separately

so the 1-5 files go to the dir1
the 6-10 files go to dir2
11-15 to dir3
etc

Yes, I tried to do it manually.. but got lost..also I need to repeat the operation with different files about ten times....  I tried to use Python for this, but I am a beginning programmer.

All I have is the text file of all files in the folder, and now I need to separate it into "modules" by 5 files and copy each one into different ascending folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the files are stored in the directory `files`, the following code iterates over all files in the directory and moves them to dirX, incrementing X every five files.

```py
import os
import shutil

filecounter = 0
dircounter = 0

directory = "files"

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    absoluteFilename = os.path.join(directory, file)

    if filecounter % 5 == 0:  # increment dir counter every five files processed
        dircounter += 1
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory, "dir"+str(dircounter)))

    targetfile = os.path.join(directory, "dir"+str(dircounter), file)  # builds absolute target filename
    shutil.move(absoluteFilename, targetfile)

    filecounter += 1
```

This uses the module operator to increment the `dircounter` every five files.

Note that the order of the files is arbitrary (see [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)). You might have to sort the list beforehand.

Comment: thanks a lot. you're the best! it worked:) despite the randomness. but whatever.